# Withdraw erc20 DAI token from smart contract but get DAI/insufficient-allowance

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, dai

I try to withdraw DAI token from smart contract into [my wallet](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xf1dba6919548027759ba74dc316f65633f9c371a#tokentxns) on [kovan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x5e7309a3a2db60a2add7fff15c862c3923db34e5#tokentxnshttps://) net that holds around 20 dai by executing the following:

```
const mantissa = (numberOfDaiTransfer * Math.pow(10, underlyingDecimals)).toString();
result = await underlying.methods.approve(myContractAddress,mantissa);
result = await underlying.methods.approve(myWalletAddress,mantissa);
result = await underlying.methods.transferFrom(myContractAddress,myWalletAddress,mantissa).send(fromMyWallet);
```

However I get [Dai/insufficient-allowance](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x637c13f5d282f0dbd9bf038573b0576d0137cfbc281a27cedc956449d149dfb0) error and the transaction gets reverted. What could be the problem?

regards

Comment: The problem is the use of `approve` and `transferFrom`. The second line is approving the contract to use your tokens. For the third line to work you need the contract to approve your address. The third line fails because the contract hasn't authorized you to access its tokens.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the contract to approve my address. I add approve(myWalletAddress) on the 3rd line, but that doesn't fix it

Comment: To approve any address the contract has to explicitly call approve from solidity: `token.approve(0x1234..., amount);`.

Comment: Token is belong to the deployer. You have to delegate or change the role of the smart contract to make any action.